# CPU usage percentage in MPI applications

Tags: performance, windows-7, mpi, cpu-usage, mpich

I used MPICH2. When I start my applications by using mpiexec, they run on the remote hosts (Win7) have 25% CPU usage. I want to increase the percentage if this can improve my application performance. I wish that my remote computers are dedicated to my calculations. How can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Let me guess: remote host use quad-core processors, but run only one instance of MPI node?

Comment: I guess that I should have known these points before starting to work on MPI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For MPI processes your # of processes should match the sum of the core count of your machines (assuming a CPU-heavy workload). If an MPI process runs with `-np 4` on a quad-core box, it will consume all four cores and you'll see your CPU usage near 100%. If it runs with `-np 1` the CPU load of the box is going to be around 25% (because only one core out of four is dedicated to your calculations). Any additional increase and they will start to contend for CPU time.